# Divide and Conquer: Strassen's Matrix Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I was wondering if there is any trick/mnemonic to remember the algorithm?

I am forgetting it every now and then.

Comment: How often do you need to implement Strassen's algorithm from memory? I'm not even sure if I could implement a correct binary heap from memory, even though it's an exceedingly simple data structure whose core I idea I know by heart and which I implemented several times.

Comment: Remembering the name makes it at least easy to do a search.